# Blender Alembic does not read frames with zero geo correctly

Tags: alembic

so I imported an alembic file of a Boolean animation from Houdini into Blender. The animation starts at frame 20, but no geometry is supposed to show up until frame 21. However, when I imported the file in Blender, frame 20 is showing the geometry at frame 21, when in fact no geometry was supposed to show up in that frame. I imported the file to Maya and there is no geo on frame 20, which is exactly how it should be. I then exported the file as alembic from Maya and imported it to Blender, and Blender stills shows the geo at frame 21 on frame 20. Anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Had this same problem. If I remember correctly I made an extra point at the origin which blender can't render points anyway but it worked out to alleviate the issue. Love Blender but the alembic support has a way to go.